# how to install os x on my MBP

Tags: macos, operating-systems, reinstall

So in my quest to do a clean install of OS X Lion, I deleted the recovery partition. I managed to install Windows 7 (Enterprise .iso from my uni), but I am having a lot of trouble figuring out a way to get OS X back on.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

The recommended path from Apple is to upgrade from the previous version. If you don't want to do that for some reason you have to get one of these: [OSX Lion USB Thumb Drive](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MD256). You can also get the .dmg from the Lion install and copy that to any USB drive but this requires access to the Snow Leopard App Store.

You can read a bit about it on this [blog](http://tonymacx86.blogspot.com/2011/08/os-x-lion-installation-usb-drive-now.html)